# Kendo UI: Conditionally preventing a Tooltip from being displayed on a Grid cell

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tooltip

I'm working on trying to display a Kendo tool tip on a grid cell, getting the content from an ajax call. My tooltip declaration looks like the below:

```
    var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.table.kendoTooltip({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        opacity: 0,
        callout: true,
        position: 'right',
        animation:
        {
            close: {
                effects: "fade:out"
            },
            open: {
                effects: "fade:in",
                duration: 1000
            }
        },
        contentTemplateId: "tooltipTemplate",
        filter: "td",
        show: function (e) {

        },
        content: function (e) {
            var target = e.target;
            currentTarget = target;

            var message = "Loading...";
            if ($(currentTarget[0]).attr("name") !== undefined) {
               //Do ajax call, show tool tip
            }
            else {
                //CLOSE THE TOOTLIP
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

In that bottom "else", I want to close or hide the tooltip since I don't have the attribute "name", which is passed into my ajax call to show the content. I've tried all of the following:

```
$("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").table.kendoTooltip.hide();
$("#myGrid").data("kendoTooltip").hide();
e.sender.popup.destroy();
e.sender.popup.hide();
e.sender.popup.close();
```

None of these work! Destroy is the closest, but I can't recreate the tool tip when I need it again. Any advice?

Comment: there seems to be a bit of a discrepancy between the question title and what you're trying to do in the content method; I suggest changing the title to something along the lines of "Conditionally preventing a Kendo UI Tooltip from being displayed"

Comment: I think that's a better title, I'll adjust it based on your suggestion

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The tooltip is implemented in a way that makes this difficult. You could call `this.hide()` wrapped in a `setTimeout`, but it will have a flicker effect. So you'll probably have to roll your own solution for this. Here's an idea to get you started:

Create a `beforeShow` pseudo-event which is triggered before the tooltip is shown (this could all be done in a more sophisticated fashion):

```
// customize the _show method to call options.beforeShow 
// to allow preventing the tooltip from being shown..
kendo.ui.Tooltip.fn._show = function (show) {
    return function (target) {
        var e = {
            sender: this,
            target: target,
            preventDefault: function () {
                this.isDefaultPrevented = true;
            }
        };

        if (typeof this.options.beforeShow === "function") {
            this.options.beforeShow.call(this, e);
        }
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented) {
            // only show the tooltip if preventDefault() wasn't called..
            show.call(this, target);
        }
    };
}(kendo.ui.Tooltip.fn._show);
```

Use it like this to conditionally prevent showing the tooltip:

```
var toolTip = $('#grid').kendoTooltip({
    filter: ".tooltip",
    beforeShow: function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).data("name") === null) {
            // don't show the tooltip if the name attribute contains null
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    content: function (e) {
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        return "<div>Hi, this is a tool tip for id " + dataItem.Id + "! </div>";
    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/qBvan/))

Comment: Once again, you've nailed it Lars. Little disappointed there isn't a more elegant solution to this problem but yours works perfectly fine

Comment: This answer is great, but I have a question: would there be an issue if you forgot specify a 'beforeShow' function in your kendoTooltip config? You seem to be replacing the _show function with a new one that does nothing if 'beforeShow' is not provided... ie wouldn't you want to just call show.call(this, target) if typeof this.options.beforeShow === "function" was false?

Comment: @snuggles You're right, of course - thanks for the hint. I updated the code.

Comment: Lars, you can add one more line of code to make Kendo recognize this new event:
kendo.ui.Tooltip.fn.events.push('beforeShow');
This enables angular integration (<div kendo-tooltip k-on-before-show="myController.handle(kendoEvent)">)

Comment: It's killing me that this is accepted when my answer is so much simpler

Answer (score 11):

I just came across this and found a solution that works very well.  The `content` event can work like a `beforeShow` event, because it is actually called before the show event is fired.  If we treat it like a `beforeShow` event we can do this

```
var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");

grid.table.kendoTooltip({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    opacity: 0,
    callout: true,
    position: 'right',
    animation:
    {
        close: {
            effects: "fade:out"
        },
        open: {
            effects: "fade:in",
            duration: 1000
        }
    },
    contentTemplateId: "tooltipTemplate",
    filter: "td",
    show: function (e) {

    },
    content: function (e) {
        var target = e.target,
        currentTarget = target;

        // hide popup as default action
        e.sender.popup.element.css("visibility", "hidden");

        if ($(currentTarget[0]).attr("name") !== undefined) {

           e.sender.popup.element.css("visibility", "visible");

           //Do ajax call, show tool tip
           $.getJSON("SomeUrl").then(function(response) {

               $(target).text(response);

           });

           return "Loading...";
        }

        return "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer - gets the job done, without the unwanted flickering, and not overcomplicated

Comment: Lol this is similar to the solution I wanted to post but there didn't seem to be any interest.

Answer (score 5):

I hope my post is not too late, but will help few of us. This can be achieved with show and  hide events where we can validate the Tooltip text and show or hide the Tooltip as below and works for me.

```
  show: function(e){
        if(this.content.text() !=""){
            $('[role="tooltip"]').css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    },
    hide: function(){
        $('[role="tooltip"]').css("visibility", "hidden");
    },
```

Full code :

```
 $("#GridId").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "td:nth-child(1)", //this filter selects the second column's cells
    position: "right",
    autoHide: false,
    show: function(e){
        if(this.content.text() !=""){
            $('[role="tooltip"]').css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    },
    hide: function(){
        $('[role="tooltip"]').css("visibility", "hidden");
    },

    content: function(e){
        var dataItem = $("#GridId").data("kendoTreeList").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
        var content = dataItem.ToolTip;
        if (content!=null) {
            return content;
        }
        else {

            return "";
        }

    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Comment: I tried this, and the `this` context was just the window for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you throw an error in the content method, this will prevent the tooltip ever showing.

```
var grid = $('#myGrid').data('kendoGrid');
grid.table.kendoTooltip({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    opacity: 0,
    callout: true,
    position: 'right',
    animation: {
        close: {
            effects: 'fade:out'
        },
        open: {
            effects: 'fade:in',
            duration: 1000
        }
    },
    contentTemplateId: 'tooltipTemplate',
    filter: 'td',
    show: function (e) { },
    content: function (e) {
        var message = 'Loading...';
        if (!$(e.target).attr('name')) {
           throw 'No name yet, don\'t show tooltip!';
        }
        //Do ajax call, show tool tip
    }
});
```

If you're waiting for an ajax response though, then just create the tooltip when the call is completed.

Comment: This both breaks into the javascript debugger if the developer console is open, and spams the log with errors.  Lar's solution isn't ideal, but these things aren't an option for some of us.

Comment: I have a better solution that involved setting some css rule beforehand which you remove if it has content, but unless someone asks for it I don't see the point taking the time.

Comment: Your answer contains errors.  You need to either escape your quote in `don\'t` or surround the error string with double quotes

Comment: Thanks you're correct! I like to use single quotes and didn't think about it

Comment: You're welcome, don't want you to get down voted for it :)

Answer (score 0):

consider something like

```
jQuery('#searchCoursesMainGrid').kendoTooltip({
    //The ">" which is the expand arrow is in its own table column. So add one more column
    //":not(:empty) is a css3 selector that checks if there is a value inside the td element"
    filter: 'td:nth-child(6):not(:empty)', //this filter selects the webNote column cells that are not empty
    position: 'right',
    autoHide: false,
    width: 500,
    content: function (e) {
      //.data('kendoGrid') is a reserved word by Kendo
      //http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields
      var dataItem = jQuery('#searchCoursesMainGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem(e.target.closest('tr'));
      var content = dataItem.webNote;
      return content;
    }
}).data('kendoTooltip');
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers aren't very good in the most recent version of Kendo. They've made it easier.

First, you'd set your filter to check for an attribute:

```
ak-tooltip="k-filter: td[tooltip]; k-content.call: getTooltipDataTemplate($event); 
k-width:auto; k-position: top;
```

Then, in the template for your grid, you'd declare the attribute for the columns that you want the tooltip to display on:

```
{
    title: 'Column A',
    field: 'ColumnA',
    sortable: {
        initialDirection: "asc"
    },
    hidden: true
},
{
    title: 'ShowToolTip',
    field: 'ShowToolTip',
    width: 500,
    attributes: {
      tooltip: true
    }
},
{
    title: 'NoToolTip',
    field: 'NoToolTip'
},
```